# Entity Framework in Web API saving single property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to save only a single property using entity framework.  My line of code that is causing the issue is;

```
db.Entry(userObject).Property(x => x.Email).IsModified = true;
```

This line was throwing a 500 Internal Server error, so I broke it down a little more to this;

```
var obj = db.Entry(userObject).Property(x => x.Email);
obj.IsModified = true;
```

It is the setting of IsModified to 'true' which is throwing the error.  I have this inside a try catch block but it doesn't even get caught.. it just jumps back to the client with a 500 internal server error.

What am I doing wrong?  The following code works fine;

```
db.Entry(userObject).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

But I don't want to save the entire object, just the email property.  Do I have to set this first anyway?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Why don't you get the entity by a Linq query, edit is email then save changes?

Comment: The entity is being sent to the Web API by the client.